# EaseInOut animtion is not working properly after iOS 17 update

Tags: swiftui

I have an EaseInOut animation view modifier that was working smoothly in iOS 16, however after upgrading to iOS 17, it's not working as expected.

It used to fade out and fade in smoothly continuously, now it does it a couple of times and then stops.

Thank you

> Blink.animation.swift

```
struct Blink: ViewModifier {

@State private var opacity = 0.0

var isActive: Bool

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    if isActive {
        content
            .opacity(self.opacity)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)
                .repeatCount(1)
                .repeatForever(autoreverses: true),
                       value: self.opacity)
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.opacity = 1
                }
            }.onChange(of: opacity) {
              print(opacity)
            }
    }
    else {
        content
    }
    
}
}
```

[image: Animation in iOS 17]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it resolved by making some changes to the opacity & the repeatCount.

Here's how I fixed it.

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
       content
           .opacity(isActive ? opacity : 1.0)
           .animation(isActive ? .easeInOut(duration: 0.5)
           .repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : nil,
                      value: opacity)
           .onAppear {
               if isActive {
                   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                       withAnimation {
                           self.opacity = 0.0
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
   }
```